# How do i accept and process an incoming parameter via URL

Tags: c#, .net

How do i Accept parameters sent over the URL (POST or GET) in a C# code? in PHP it can be done by simply using **$_REQUEST**

Anything similar in C# .NET 3.5?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC?  ASP.NET Web Forms?  Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Request.QueryString["parametername"]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx